# Python Post request for image

Tags: python, image, file, upload, http-post

I'm trying to convert this request into Python's requests but it seems like I got some error. It works fine with curl. The api I used: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/ikxck0/p_turn_images_into_cartoon_ready_to_use_api_is/

(myobama.png) is my local image

```
curl -X POST "https://master-white-box-cartoonization-psi1104.endpoint.ainize.ai/predict" -H "accept: image/jpg" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file_type=image" -F "source=@myobama.png;type=image/png" > img.png
```

My current Python post request, which results in {"message":"Error! Please upload another file"}

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'image/jpg',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

files = {
    'file_type': 'image',
    'source': open('myobama.png;type=image/png', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('https://master-white-box-cartoonization-psi1104.endpoint.ainize.ai/predict', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the documentation it seems that your `files` dictionary is missing the key `file`. See https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

**EDITED**
Please, check **UPDATED** section. This is no longer valid.

```
files = { 'file': ('myobama.png', open('myobama.png;type=image/png', 'rb'), 'image/png')}
```

---

**UPDATED**

After some `curl` / `requests` comparison and debugging, this should be the headers and files objects:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'image/png'
}

files = { 
    'file_type': (None, 'image'),
    'source': ('myobama.png', open('myobama.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')
}
```

I tested it myself and it works as expected. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it contain the key "source" instead of "file" key, but it doesn't work for both case.

Comment: I got it to work. Please, check the "UPDATED" section in my answer.